# Run -jar with args and use args in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jar, args

I need to run jar with static parameter, for example, java -jar myapp-1.0.0.jar /path/static/myfolder, and use this path "/path/static/myfolder" in my code. So, I know how to get this parameters in PSVM (String..args), but how to get it in Spring? Is there annotation for this or may be in properties file>

Comment: This seems to be what I need
https://springhow.com/spring-boot-application-arguments/

Answer (score 0):

For example: `java -jar -Dtest=abcd myapp-1.0.0.jar`.

You can use `System.getProperty("test")` to get value.

`-D{parameter}` needs to be before that jar

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is really answer for my question:

create special @Component that implements CommandLineRunner and override method Run, like this:

```
@Component public class StartupPrintRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

private String folder;

@Override public void run(String... args) throws Exception { 
this.folder = Arrays.deepToString(args); }
}
```

Inject bean StartupPrintRunner where you need and get parameters. It returns String looks like an array: `[parameter1, parameter2.., parameter n]` and we can parse it to get necessary paarameter.

Comment: For more information you can look here: https://springhow.com/spring-boot-application-arguments/